# Translating SQL to C#: Select name in key-value pair with the highest value after applying a function to its value and filtering based on a condition?

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary, t-sql, max

I have the following almost-English SQL.

```
SELECT [NAME]
FROM [PAIRS]
WHERE condition([NAME])
HAVING function([SCORE]) = MAX(function([SCORE]))
```

Assume that:

- `PAIRS` is a two-column table translating a string `NAME` to a numeric `SCORE` (i.e. in C# terms, it's a dictionary).
- `condition` takes a `NAME` and returns a boolean.
- `function` translates a numeric `SCORE` to some other value.

How can I re-write this SQL in C#? My best attempt so far relied on abuse of `Aggregate`. This felt terribly over-engineered and far inferior to my almost-English SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not...

```cs
int foo(int i) => i;

var pairs = new List<(string name, int score)>
{
   ("a", 1),
   ("b", 2),
   ("c", 2)
};

var result = pairs
   .Where
   (
      p => p.name == "c"
      && foo(p.score) == pairs.Max(p => foo(p.score))
   );
```